# Tell me why I can also access as an array as an object

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**Create a Stripe Product object.**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_××××××");

$product = \Stripe\Product::create([
    'name' => 'My SaaS Platform',
    'type' => 'service',
]);
```

---

**Get the id of the Product object**

```
echo $product->id;
```

·  I can understand the above code

```
echo $product['id'];
```

· I can not understand the above code

・What is the reason why the returned value should be an object but can be accessed in an array?

Comment: I can not understand your question.

Comment: `implements \ArrayAccess`?

Comment: `$product` is an `object` of class `\Stripe\Product` so you can not access it as an `array`

Comment: Yes they can. PHP can convert objects to arrays seamlessly. They are asking why they can as it's an object and not an array. PHP does its own typecasting

Comment: @Thomas I did not know that.

Comment: It's exactly as @mario points out. `Product` extends `ApiResource` which extends [`StripeObject`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/StripeObject.php) which implements `ArrayAccess`. Have a read of the PHP docs ~ http://php.net/manual/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: just a side note... some objects can be accessed through array access, others, especially those in the core, will throw a Fatal Error if you try to access a object property via a array element!... PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object property of type mysqli as array element, that's just one, their are many others too! PHP 5.2 to 7>>>

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the object (such as the return value from the API) is implements ArrayAccess?